# Where is documentation for Core App C++/WinRT?

Tags: c++, uwp, c++-winrt

I am trying to develop apps in Core App C++/WinRT. I notice that it has a wWinMain entry point, so I am assuming it supports code from Windows Desktop Application. I cannot find documentation specific to Core App C++/WinRT. Should I be using the W32 documentation on msdn? When I try to add sample code from Windows Desktop Applications I cannot access header files such as winuser.h. I am using Visual Studio 2022, so the windowsapp.lib should already be included (I have also tried adding the windowsapp in a pragma comment directive). Can someone help?

Comment: You're conflating several things that aren't related. Import libraries are neither included, nor does the linker have any effect on the compiler. It's unclear which API you are trying to use that requires that you include winuser.h. It's unclear what *"I cannot access header files"* means. As such it's pretty unlikely that this question can be answered.

Answer (score 1):

Core App (C++/WinRT) is a project template for a Universal Windows Platform (UWP) app that doesn't use XAML. Instead, it uses the C++/WinRT Windows namespace header for the Windows.ApplicationModel.Core namespace. After building and running, click on an empty space to add a colored square; then click on a colored square to drag it. You could know about this from the document: [Introduction to C++/WinRT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/intro-to-using-cpp-with-winrt#core-app-cwinrt).